# Problems with socket policy file on flash/flex clients

Tags: flash, xml

I have a MMO using a flash/flex (AS3) client that needs to make a raw socket connection to our server.  I have tried several different methods of serving the xml policy file on port 843 as detailed by Adobe.

Now everything seems to work fine for most clients, but a large percentage (20% ?) of our clients cannot connect to this magic port (843) and get the xml policy file.  Our clients are just random people out on the net, so we have no control and no real info about their environment.

I'm logging the success/fail of client connections by having the client send me an email via php, so either way these users have net access, but cannot get the magic policy file.  So far it doesn't seem to matter what OS/browser or even flash version they are using...

Right now I'm just trying to determine if the problems are server side, client side or somewhere in between.

Has anyone else has similar experience with Flash's new socket policy stuff and what can/may cause clients not to connect to the magic 843 port ?

Is there an 'official' policy server that I can try to at least rule out my code as a potential problem ?

Thank-you very much !

Colin

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these users are behind a firewall which prevents them from connecting to the 843 port?
For an 'offical' flashpolicyd see: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html